# @“Data Source=(local)\ SIRSYSTEM \ HEY;” – can’t connect if a string includes SIRSYSTEM

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server

The name of my MS Sql server instance is HEY, but when trying to log on to Sql server via Microsoft Sql management studio, the login window displays as the name of a server 
"SIRSYSTEM\HEY".

What  is SIRSYSTEM? A name of default server instance? If so, then why can’t I connect to HEY using the following connection string ( in Ado.net ):

@"Data Source=(local)\ SIRSYSTEM \ HEY;Initial Catalog=FilmClub;"+
                "Integrated Security=true";

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIRSYSTEM is the server or workstation name hosting the instance; to connect to, it the datasource would be either .\HEY, or SIRSYSTEM\HEY, get rid of the (local)\

Answer (score 0):

SIRSYSTEM is not a system name but likely something that you or someone typed at some point as the default or is it the name of the server itself?

Data Source=(local)\SIRSYSTEM\HEY is not at all valid. Try just (local)\HEY.

You might have to unregister and then reregister the server instance within management studio to change this.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use 'Hey', SIRSYSTEM is the name of the computer.

Or: `localhost\HEY`